# ActiveMQ Artemis Topic listener not able to recieve the message using Spring @JmsListener

Tags: spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I have a topic created using the configuration

```java
@Bean
public ActiveMQTopic sampleTopic(){
    return new org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQTopic("topic1");
}
```

The listener configuration is like this:

```java
@Bean   
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> topicJmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory returnValue = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    returnValue.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    returnValue.setSubscriptionShared(true);
    returnValue.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
    returnValue.setPubSubDomain(Boolean.TRUE);
    return returnValue;
}
```

I am sending a message to this topic. The sender looks like this:

```java
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(sampleTopic, jsonMessage, m -> {
    m.setStringProperty("typ", "new");
    m.setStringProperty("sender", "abc");

    return m;
});
```

It works fine. I could see the message in Artemis console.

I configured the listener like this.

```java
public class TopicReceiver {
    @JmsListener(destination = "topic1",
                 containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory",
                 subscription = "sub _new",
                 selector = "type = 'new' and sender = 'abc'")
    @Transactional
    public void onMessageKundeAbholauftragNew(String payload) {
        System.out.println(payload);
    }
}
```

But the message is not being received in the listener. Can anyone help?  Do I need to configure anything else?

Also, I noted that the messages is present under the anycast-> topic1. The subscriptions "new" under multicast says have zero messages. So I guess somehow the message is not routed to the subscription? Or Is it something else?

Comment: Have you tried without the selector?

Comment: Yes i tried, but  its not working

Comment: Is th eTopicReceiver annotated with @Component?

Comment: Oops!i missed that. With @Component annotaion added to the Reciever without Selector and subscription it is working. But i really need it to work with selector and subscription :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the message with the property `typ` with the value `new`, but your selector is looking for `type`.

Also, the `subscription` parameter for your `@JmsListener` is `sub _new`. This almost certainly shouldn't have a space in it, but should rather be `sub_new`.